# Indexing list of lists

Tags: r, list

Let's say I have a list of lists called lst

```
x<-as.list(runif(10, 1, 10))
y<-as.list(runif(10, 11, 20))
z<-as.list(runif(10, 20, 30))

lst<-list(x,y,z)
```

If I want the first entry of each sub-list, I can do

```
lapply(lst, "[[", 1)
```

But let's say I want the first and second entry of each sub-list. Attempting to do the following gives me an error:

```
lapply(lst, "[[", 1:2)

Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
```

How would I go about grabbing the first and second entry of each sub-list in one call?

Comment: "If I want the first entry of each sub-list, I can do `lapply(lst, "[[", 1)`" Thank you! I've been looking all over the place for how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need

```
 lapply(lst, "[", 1:2)
```

Or

```
 do.call(c,lapply(lst, "[", 1:2))
```

According to ?"[["

> The most important distinction between ‘[’, ‘[[’ and ‘$’ is that
>        the ‘[’ can select more than one element whereas the other two
>        select a single element.

Comment: Some explanation might be in order. Any advantage of `do.call(c, ...)` to `as.list(unlist(...))`? (+1)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if there is a speed advantage for `as.list(unlist(`

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of using "[" because I'm used to using "[[" to subset lists. Seems silly that I hadn't thought of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Depends also on the order you want the results.  @akrun gives you from each list 
1st, 2nd, 1st, 2nd, 1st, 2nd.
Here is a different ways that gives you 
1st, 1st, 1st, 2nd, 2nd, 2nd

```
lapply(1:2, function(x) lapply(lst, "[[", x))
```

Comment: Thanks. The order isn't important for my particular case, but this is good to know